# Rails 4 - will_paginate and mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, pagination, mongoid

I'm getting a no method error when trying to implement pagination on my rails project.
`undefined method 'paginate' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x007fb256e54588>`
In my controller I have:
`@user = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)`
In my index.html.erb file I have `<%= will_paginate @user %>` above my html `<table>` tag and below the closing html `</table>` tag
I have the will_paginate and mongoid-pagination gems installed properly. And I have tried restarting the dev server.. Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`will_paginate_mongoid` gem](https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid):

> It just creates a paginate method compatible with will_paginate interface [...]

The `mongoid-pagination` gem requires you to manually `include Mongoid::Pagination` in your models and doesn't specifically integrate with the `will_paginate` gem.

Answer (score 0):

The will_paginate gem has support for Mongoid out of the box.

```
require 'will_paginate/mongoid'
```

In your controller action

```
User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```